# For Ruby on Rails, is there a way to print out the web server's name (such as apache), possibly by Rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

If I am running a Rails 2 or Rails 3 app, is there a way to print out the web server's name on a page (such as `/foos/index`)... or if Rails doesn't have any knowledge what the server is, can Rack do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CGI environment, the `SERVER_SOFTWARE` variable contains the name of the web server (and its version, unless the web server is configured to exclude this).

For Rails, you can use `ENV['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` anywhere to obtain the web server name.

For Rack applications, you can use `env['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` where `env` is available.

Comment: oh... from your info, it seems like Rails has limited knowledge in ENV, not even the user_agent string... but `request.env['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` works.

Comment: I guess if you are running a Rails 2 or 3 app using Rack, then how do you get Rack to print it out? (where is the Rack's `env` available?)

Comment: Rack is used internally by Rails, you don't have access to it from normal controllers. However, if you have created a Rack application (which is essentially nothing more than a simple method accepting one parameter (`env`) and returning a HTTP status code, headers and body content), you can create a route pointing to the Rack application. As for the user agent, the environment variable is `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. Be sure to include the `HTTP_`, as it's coming from a HTTP header.

Comment: by user_agent I mean `HTTP_USER_AGENT`.  The key is not about the spelling of it... it is more about `ENV` vs `request.env`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this?

One common reason is for debugging - if one server is having a problem, it would be nice to know which server.

A better way to aid debugging is to include a custom header with the server name. You can write a simple Rack middleware that will do that.

```
# lib/rack/server_name_header.rb
module Rack
  class ServerNameHeader
    attr_reader :app, :hostname
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
      @hostname = `hostname`
    end
    def call(env)
      status, headers, body = *app.call(env)
      headers['X-Server-Name'] = hostname
      [status, headers, body]
    end
  end
end

# config/environments/production.rb
require File.expand_path('../../../lib/rack/server_name_header', __FILE__)
My::Application.configure do
  config.middleware.use Rack::ServerNameHeader
  # all the other stuff
end
```